# NServiceBus 4.6.5 Master fails to Install

Tags: installation, nservicebus

I'm running NServiceBus installer 4.6.1 in a configuration with 3 servers: 1 Master and 2 Workers.

I installed successfully 1 Worker with the following command:

```
NServiceBus.Host.exe Worker.Profiles.MyProduction /install /serviceName:Worker /displayName:"My Worker"
```

I tried to do the same for the Master server with the following command:

```
NServiceBus.Host.exe Worker.Profiles.MyProduction NServiceBus.Master NServiceBus.PerformanceCounters /install /serviceName:Worker /displayName:"My Worker"
```

It throws the following error:

> 2017-03-21 11:54:01,351 [1] INFO
> NServiceBus.ConfigureRavenPersistence [(null)]  <(null)> - Connection
> to RavenDB at http://localhost:8080 verified. Detected ve rsion:
> Product version: 2.0.3 / 5a4b7ea, Build version: 2375 2017-03-21
> 11:54:01,476 [1] WARN  NServiceBus.Installation.GatewayHttpListenerIn
> staller [(null)] <(null)> - Failed to grant to grant user
> 'DEVDOMAIN\myuser' HttpListener permissions. Processing will
> continue. Try running the following command from an admin console:
> netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost/Worker/
> user="DEVDOMAIN\myuser"
>
> The error message from running the above command is: Url reservation
> add failed, Error: 87 The parameter is incorrect. 2017-03-21
> 11:54:01,476 [1] INFO  NServiceBus.Persistence.Raven.RavenUserInstall
> er [(null)] <(null)> - Adding user 'DEVDOMAIN\myuser' to raven.
> Instance:'http://localhost:8080', Database:'Worker'. 2017-03-21
> 11:54:01,788 [1] INFO  NServiceBus.Installation.PerformanceMonitorUse
> rsInstaller [(null)] <(null)> - Skipped adding user
> 'DEVDOMAIN\myuser' to gro up 'Performance Monitor Users' because
> the user is already in group.

So I tried the command sugested from the command line cmd as an administrator:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost/Worker/ user="DEVDOMAIN\myuser"
```

and I still get the following error:

> Url reservation add failed, Error: 87 The parameter is incorrect.

How can NServiceBus be installed in my Master Server?

Comment: according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307223(v=vs.85).aspx the user parameter doesn't need to be in quotation marks, does it change anything when you remove them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When specifying a URLACL the port number must be supplied which is why it's throwing a parameters incorrect message.

i.e if the port is supposed to be port 80 then the command line should be:

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost:80/Worker/ user="DEVDOMAIN\myuser"`